# Cannot install R packages on a UNIX system

Tags: rhel, r

I'm trying to install R packages (including ggplot2) on a UNIX system but receive the following error messages:

```
c++ -m64 -std=c++11 -I"/usr/local/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -Itestthat  -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -fpic -c clip-lines.cpp -o clip-lines.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
make: *** [clip-lines.o] Error 1
```

This problem occurs with any version of R - I've tried on 3.6.3 and 4.0.5.

Apparently, the problem may be related to the ~/.R/Makevars file, but I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: What C++ compiler are you using? It apparently doesn’t support C++11.

Comment: gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-23)

Comment: You say "Unix system" but have tagged this as linux.   If you're running linux, why not install your distro's R packages?

Comment: Is your version of redhat 4.4 ? or  I misread ?

Comment: GCC 4.4.7 is for RHEL 6 which has been EOL since Nov 30th 2020. Considering that nearly every R package is going to need at least C++11 to compile, you're going to run into the same issue. You could compile a later version of GCC but the best thing to do is to move to supported version of RHEL like 7 or 8.

Comment: ... and if you upgrade to RHEL 7, you’ll be able to install R packages from EPEL.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by typing the following in the terminal:

```
scl enable devtoolset-6 bash
```

Now the packages are installing fine.